# Page_Init vs Page_Load - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I seem to have to choose between `Page_Init`, if I want my Crystal Report to not prompt for parameters on page change. Or `Page_Load` if I want my dropdown list to work correctly in order to set a parameter. I want to do both though!

I assume this is because the dropdownlist doesn't exist during `Page_Init`? How can I make this work? Relevant code is below:

```
ReportDocument rptDoc;
dsfeeEarnings ds1;
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    ds1 = new dsfeeEarnings();
    dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Fee Earnings";
    dt = getFeeEarnings1();
    ds1.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
    rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Report.rpt"));
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
}
```

`dsfeeEarnings` is a `.xsd` file that goes with the report.
`getFeeEarnings1()` is the method that deals with the dropdown list's value and goes off to run a stored procedure using that value.

I have tried putting the code above into a `if (!IsPostBack)` block but that seems to stop the report from working at all.

I tried creating a session instead, this helped with the dropdown list but hte report was still asking for the parameters each time I changed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the following code:

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dsfeeEarnings ds = new dsfeeEarnings();

    rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("FeeEarningsReport.rpt"));
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
    dt = getFeeEarnings1();
    ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
}
```